# Java AsyncTask Looking for an Alternative to Get() because i need it to loop in the thread itself rather than creating a new thread?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I need the doinBackground() to loop/wait for the data to be recieved before calling onPostExecute();

Data Calls From Firebase has a wait time. I know we have a get() function, but that kind of is a waist of milliseconds, I am looking for a workaround in which I don't need to do a boolean check, just simply wait for the data and then call the next thread from there. this way the transition can move smoothly.

```
private class GetDatafromFirebaseLoop extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{
        private boolean dataRecieved = false;
        String FirstName,MiddleName,LastName;

        @Override protected void onPreExecute() {
            User.Id = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override public void run() {
                    mTitle.setText("UserId : ");
                    mQuestion.setText(User.Id);
                }
            });
            super.onPreExecute();
        }
        @Override protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
           FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("UsersInfo").child(Users.Id).addListenerForSingleValueEvent((new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    if (dataSnapshot.exists() && dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount() > 0) {
                        Map<String, Object> map = (Map<String, Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
                        if (map.get("FirstName") != null) {
                            FirstName = map.get("FirstName").toString();
                        }
                        if (map.get("MiddleName") != null) {
                            MiddleName = map.get("MiddleName").toString();
                        }
                        if (map.get("LastName") != null) {
                            LastName = map.get("LastName").toString();
                        }
                    }
                }
                @Override public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
            }));
            return null;
        }
        @Override protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            if(dataRecieved){
                dataRecieved = false;
                mTitle.setText("FullName");
                mQuestion.setText(FirstName + " " + MiddleName + " " + LastName);
                New RunNewAsyncTask().execute();// Which also continues this same format for other data.

            }
            else {
                execute(new Runnable() {
                    @Override public void run() {
                        doInBackground();
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You don't need to put a Realtime Database listener in an AsyncTask.  All Firebase APIs are already asynchronous and won't block the main thread.

Comment: Hey Doug, Thanks for that, This is just sample code, my Code setup is different, all Strings are Global Stored Variables. this way to help with Global Variables that are all working Asycroniously .... Think of it as a parent calling Function Which Has Multiple Children Global Variables Just waiting for it to Load up and then those Tasks are called seperately.

Comment: Maybe you could rewrite the sample to remove the async task and explain what isn't working the way you expect?

Comment: The Problem is Basically i want to run the New RunNewAsyncTask().execute(); which is inside the onPost Execute but for that I need the FirstName,MiddleName,LastName Data Retrieved from the doInBackground before I can Run it, It always Shows up empty.

Comment: Again, I suggest removing the async task as it's only unnecessarily complicating this work.

Comment: So Run it as a Function on the Main Thread ? and keep looping it like a normal function ? and run the UI Seperately ? Really trying to avoid this process

Comment: As I said, Firebase APIs are asynchronous and don't block the main thread.  Pretty much all sample code you will see with Firebase APIs will not use asynctask.

Comment: Your Correct, And I understand, However still trying to find an Alternative approach for a custom reason.